# Importing Data from TFS 2015 to Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, tfs-migration

I am completely newbie to TFS. Need some help on Migration. We have a VS TFS 2015 and the requirement is to move a certain code with history and all the work items from current VS TFS 2015 to new VS TFS 2015. How can I achieve this. Any pointers will be of great help.
Just additional info. The current VS TFS 2015 was build by us on Azure and the new one is provisioned through Azure SAAS.

Comment: Which server are you using? Visual Studio Team Services or on-premise TFS server?

Comment: We are using Visual Studio Team Services. And also need to migrate the source code from VSTS VC to VSTS VC.

Comment: Are you going to move them to a different team project in the same VSTS account or move to a different VSTS account? And which version control are you using? TFVC or Git?

Comment: VSTS and TFS are not the same thing.  VSTS is *NOT* TFS 2015.  Yes, they provide similar functionality, but they are different products with different policies.  Are you saying you want to move from VSTS to TFS 2015 that you have installed to an Azure IaaS instance?  Or the other way around?  Moving from a TFS instance in Azure to VSTS?  There is no official way to migrate from TFS to VSTS, but there are some tools to help.  Read this https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/adopting-vsts

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT We are moving to a different VSTS account.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch No we are not moving from VSTS to TFS 2015 we are moving from VSTS to VSTS. From manually installed VSTS to a SAAS provided VSTS. Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem here is there's no such thing as a "manually installed VSTS".  There is only VSTS.  If you have TFS installed into a Virtual Machine in Azure, that is not VSTS, that's TFS.  VSTS is SaaS, there is no non-SaaS version of VSTS.  If you're moving from TFS in Azure to VSTS then the link I provided above is still valid.

Comment: VSTS does not need to install manually, do you mean from on-premise TFS to VSTS?

Comment: Yeah Guys .. Sorry for being a dumb .. Its on premise TFS 2015 to VSTS. I tried the TFS migration tool but was not lucky .. Please point me to something concrete. I guess i need to learn about TFS and VSTS before i go ahead but no time for that :(

Comment: Which "TFS migration tool" are you referring to?  What does "was not lucky" mean?  What exactly was the problem?

Comment: TFS Integration Tool ... When i try to connect to my on premise TFS server using the add server i am not able to

Comment: @Pravin -  just added an answer that should address the current situation you are in.

Answer (score 1):

We don't widely support (as of August 3, 2016) importing your data from Team Foundation Server to Visual Studio Team Services.  However, we have been working on a full-fidelity data import utility that will let you do this.  It's currently in Private Preview and we're testing it out with a handful of customers at the moment.  We've also shared some details with our [Microsoft MVPs](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/MvpSearch?ex=Visual%20Studio%20and%20Development%20Technologies) so if you have an MVP that is helping you, they will be able to help you migrate.

Feel free to vote on this User Voice item and we'll keep everyone updated there on our progress:  [Import data from TFS On-Premises](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2264946-import-data-from-tfs-on-prem-into-vs-team-services)

Tip:  When the TFS to VSTS Data Import utility does become available, you'll want to make sure your TFS server is upgraded to the latest version of TFS including the latest update.  At the moment, that would be [Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2015-update3-vs).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2).

> OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility : Supports migration of source
>   code and work items from TFS 2010, TFS 2012, TFS 2013, and TFS 2015 to
>   Visual Studio Team Services.

Comment: It looks like Pravin is trying to go the other way:  Exporting from Visual Studio Team Services to Team Foundation Server.  The OpsHub tool would not support the opposite direction scenario.

Comment: I tried OPsHub Visual Studio tool .. but it has limitation of 2500 work item for free tier usgae. :(